# CorePlot 1.5.1: Getting error "Undefined symbols for arch armv7"

Tags: objective-c, swift, error-handling, core-plot, cocoapods

I've just installed CorePlot 1.5.1 via CocoaPods and when trying to build with these settings:

- Architectures: Standard architectures (armv7, arm64)
- Base SDK: Latest iOS (iOS 8.1)
- Build Active Architectures Only: Yes
- Valid Architectures: arm64, armv7, armv7s

I face multiple of these errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTXYGraph", referenced from:
__TMaCSo10CPTXYGraph in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've already checked the internet and tried different settings for hours but one way or another; I keep receiving errors so I decided to go from here and ask for your advise that is much appreciated!

Comment: Release builds should have "Build Active Architectures Only" set to `No`, but otherwise those settings look correct. Do you get any other build errors?

Comment: When building on a real iOS device everything works fine. Meanwhile I can also build again on the simulator (where I kept getting such errors) BUT as soon as the app starts on the simulator it crashes with: dyld: Symbol not found: _ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter, refrenced from: .../.../..., exptected in: flat namespase in .../.../... (I'm using parse, maybe that's another, new issue now)

Comment: `_ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter` is not a Core Plot symbol. All Core Plot classes, methods, and functions have a "CPT" prefix.